# Are all Kanji characters in UTF-8 3 bytes long?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, cjk

Can someone please confirm that all Kanji characters in Chinese are 3 bytes long in UTF-8?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The commonly used Hanzi/Kanji characters are in the "CJK Unified Ideographs" block between U+4E00 and U+9FFF, and take 3 bytes in UTF-8.  (The Japanese Hiragana and Katakana characters also take 3 bytes.)

However, there are also some very rarely-used characters in the "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B" and "CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement" blocks, which take 4 bytes in UTF-8.

Also be aware that Chinese text often contains ASCII characters like the digits 0-9.

Comment: Japanese text sourced from Shift-JIS is also likely to contain other non-Kanji, non-ASCII characters mapping to two-byte sequences. And then we'll shortly have the emoji to contend with, which are also outside the Basic Multilingual Plane and so 4 bytes...

Comment: @sleske: No, I don't *speak* Chinese.  I've just done way too much work with character encoding.

Comment: @sleske and also... this is the internet. SO has most likely people who speak languages you haven't even heard of.

Comment: See also this question over on the Japanese stack exchange: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6872/16273  -- apparently some of the "rarely-used" characters aren't all that rare.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Kanji is U+4e00 to U+9faf, UTF8 3 bytes are U+0800 to U+FFFF.