# Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, uppercase

I'd like to capitalize the first letter of a `&str`. It's a simple problem and I hope for a simple solution. Intuition tells me to do something like this:

```
let mut s = "foobar";
s[0] = s[0].to_uppercase();
```

But `&str`s can't be indexed like this. The only way I've been able to do it seems overly convoluted. I convert the `&str` to an iterator, convert the iterator to a vector, upper case the first item in the vector, which creates an iterator, which I index into, creating an `Option`, which I unwrap to give me the upper-cased first letter. Then I convert the vector into an iterator, which I convert into a `String`, which I convert to a `&str`.

```
let s1 = "foobar";
let mut v: Vec<char> = s1.chars().collect();
v[0] = v[0].to_uppercase().nth(0).unwrap();
let s2: String = v.into_iter().collect();
let s3 = &s2;
```

Is there an easier way than this, and if so, what? If not, why is Rust designed this way?

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342805/how-do-i-collect-from-multiple-iterator-types#)

Comment: *It's a simple problem* — no, it's not. Please capitalize `ß` when interpreted as German. Hint: it's not a single character. Even the problem statement can be complicated. For example, it would be improper to capitalize the first character of the surname `von Hagen`. This is all an aspect of living in a global world that has had thousands of years of divergent cultures with different practices and we are trying to squash all those into 8 bits and 2 lines of code.

Comment: What you pose seems to be a character encoding problem, not a data type problem. I presume char::to_uppercase already properly handles Unicode. My question is, why the need for all data type conversions? It seems indexing could return a multi-byte, Unicode character (not a single byte character, which would assume ascii only), and to_uppercase could return an upper case character in whatever language it's in, if one is available in said language.

Comment: @marshallm `char::to_uppercase` indeed handles this problem, but you throw away its efforts by only taking the first code point (`nth(0)`) instead of all the code points that make up the capitalization

Comment: Character encoding is not a straightforward process as pointed out by [Joel on Software: Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @Shepmaster, in *general* you are correct. It's a simple problem in English (the de facto standard base of programming languages and data formats). Yes there are scripts where "capitalization" is not even a concept, and others where it is very complicated.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

## Why is it so convoluted?

Let's break it down, line-by-line

```
let s1 = "foobar";
```

We've created a literal string that is encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). UTF-8 allows us to encode the 1,114,112 [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) in a manner that's pretty compact if you come from a region of the world that types in mostly characters found in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), a standard created in 1963. UTF-8 is a *variable length* encoding, which means that a single code point might [take from 1 to 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9533258/155423). The shorter encodings are reserved for ASCII, but [many Kanji take 3 bytes in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3678752/155423).

```
let mut v: Vec<char> = s1.chars().collect();
```

This creates a vector of `char`acters. A character is a 32-bit number that directly maps to a code point. If we started with ASCII-only text, we've quadrupled our memory requirements. If we had a bunch of characters from [the astral plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)), then maybe we haven't used that much more.

```
v[0] = v[0].to_uppercase().nth(0).unwrap();
```

This grabs the first code point and requests that it be converted to an uppercase variant. Unfortunately for those of us who grew up speaking English, there's [not always a simple one-to-one mapping of a "small letter" to a "big letter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491680/unicode-characters-having-asymmetric-upper-lower-case-why). Side note: we call them upper- and lower-case [because one box of letters was above the other box of letters back in the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Type_cases).

This code will panic when a code point has no corresponding uppercase variant. I'm not sure if those exist, actually. It could also semantically  fail when a code point has an uppercase variant that has multiple characters, such as the German `ß`. Note that ß may never actually be capitalized in The Real World, this is the just example I can always remember and search for. As of 2017-06-29, in fact, the official rules of German spelling have been updated so that [**both** "ẞ" and "SS" are valid capitalizations](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_PM_2017-06-29_Aktualisierung_Regelwerk.pdf)!

```
let s2: String = v.into_iter().collect();
```

Here we convert the characters back into UTF-8 and require a new allocation to store them in, as the original variable was stored in constant memory so as to not take up memory at run time.

```
let s3 = &s2;
```

And now we take a reference to that `String`.

> It's a simple problem

Unfortunately, this is not true. Perhaps we should endeavor to convert the world to [Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto)?

> I presume `char::to_uppercase` already properly handles Unicode.

Yes, I certainly hope so. Unfortunately, Unicode isn't enough in all cases.
 Thanks to [huon for pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406793/why-is-capitalizing-the-first-letter-of-a-string-so-convoluted-in-rust/38406885#comment64297807_38406885) the [Turkish I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I), where both the upper (**İ**) and lower case (**i**) versions have a dot. That is, there is no *one* proper capitalization of the letter `i`; it depends on the [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) of the the source text as well.

> why the need for all data type conversions?

Because the data types you are working with are important when you are worried about correctness and performance. A `char` is 32-bits and a string is UTF-8 encoded. They are different things.

> indexing could return a multi-byte, Unicode character

There may be some mismatched terminology here. A `char` *is* a multi-byte Unicode character.

*Slicing* a string is possible if you go byte-by-byte, but the standard library will panic if you are not on a character boundary.

One of the reasons that indexing a string to get a character was never implemented is because so many people misuse strings as arrays of ASCII characters. Indexing a string to *set* a character could never be efficient - you'd have to be able to replace 1-4 bytes with a value that is also 1-4 bytes, causing the rest of the string to bounce around quite a lot.

> `to_uppercase` could return an upper case character

As mentioned above, `ß` is a single character that, when capitalized, becomes **two characters**.

## Solutions

See also [trentcl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571882/155423) which only uppercases ASCII characters.

### Original

If I had to write the code, it'd look like:

```
fn some_kind_of_uppercase_first_letter(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = s.chars();
    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(f) => f.to_uppercase().chain(c).collect(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", some_kind_of_uppercase_first_letter("joe"));
    println!("{}", some_kind_of_uppercase_first_letter("jill"));
    println!("{}", some_kind_of_uppercase_first_letter("von Hagen"));
    println!("{}", some_kind_of_uppercase_first_letter("ß"));
}
```

But I'd probably search for [uppercase](https://crates.io/search?q=uppercase) or [unicode](https://crates.io/search?q=unicode) on crates.io and let someone smarter than me handle it.

### Improved

Speaking of "someone smarter than me", [Veedrac points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406793/why-is-capitalizing-the-first-letter-of-a-string-so-convoluted-in-rust/38406885?noredirect=1#comment65003459_38406885) that it's probably more efficient to convert the iterator back into a slice after the first capital codepoints are accessed. This allows for a `memcpy` of the rest of the bytes.

```
fn some_kind_of_uppercase_first_letter(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = s.chars();
    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(f) => f.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str(),
    }
}
```

Comment: After thinking about it a lot, I understand these design choices better. The standard library should choose the most versatile, performant, and safe trade-offs possible. Otherwise, it forces developers to make trade-offs that might not be appropriate for their application, architecture, or locale. Or it could lead to ambiguity and misunderstandings. If I prefer other trade-offs, I can choose a 3rd-party library or write it myself.

Comment: @marshallm that's really great to hear! I fear that many newcomers to Rust misunderstand the decisions that the Rust designers have made and simply write them off as being too complicated for no benefit. By asking and answering questions here, I have gained an appreciation for the care that needs to go into such designs and hopefully become a better programmer. Keeping an open mind and being willing to learn more is a great trait to have as a programmer.

Comment: The ["Turkish i"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) is an example of locale dependence that is more directly relevant to this particular question than sorting.

Comment: I'm surprised they have to_uppercase and to_lowercase but not to_titlecase. IIRC, some unicode characters actually have a special titlecase variant.

Comment: FYI, `Some(f) => f.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str()` will be faster.

Comment: @Veedrac I never remember to look to see what special methods exist on iterators...

Comment: Rust's documentation has so much fun stuff squirreled away in places you'd never expect. It's like being on an easter egg hunt, only with new chocolate every six weeks. That aside, I implore you to keep teaching me [historical knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Type_cases) in your other answers :).

Comment: By the way, even a single code point may not be the right unit to convert. What if the first character is a grapheme cluster that should receive special handling when upper-casing? (It so happens that decomposed umlauts work if you just upper-case the base character, but I don't know if that is universally true.)

Comment: I've only ever used [`unicode-segmentation`](https://github.com/unicode-rs/unicode-segmentation) crate and I never had problems with it, so I think I can recommend it here. It is lightweight, specifically handles grapheme clusters that @SebastianRedl mentioned and follows the standard.

Comment: I needed to add an extra check on top of `fn title` to ensure it is not performed for non ascii `if !self.is_ascii() {return self.to_string()}`

Comment: The answer is incorrect as it doesn't handle characters which have two letters. Correct answer would use titlecase, not uppercase.

Comment: @MarkusLaire it feels as if you didn’t read the answer at all, skipping directly to the code which has a number of limitations *as described in the rest of the answer*. You also don’t provide a concrete example demonstrating the problem you mention and changed the problem to a different one from the original poster (titlecase vs uppercase). The question and answer are describing **why it’s hard** — does this answer not do that? Example of this code with a letter that becomes two;  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09ca0dd1b085480487fb15b2132a2031

Comment: As someone who recently was working with non-ASCII chars in javascript, I can say that this problem of multi-byte chars is not unique to rust. The solution for replacing one char with another in a string was not only convoluted, but the correct way to do it depended on exactly which chars were being swapped out.

Comment: What does the <String> after collect do...?

Answer (score 27):

> Is there an easier way than this, and if so, what? If not, why is Rust designed this way?

Well, yes and no. Your code is, as the other answer pointed out, not correct, and will panic if you give it something like བོད་སྐད་ལ་. So doing this with Rust's standard library is even harder than you initially thought.

However, Rust is designed to encourage code reuse and make bringing in libraries easy. So the idiomatic way to capitalize a string is actually quite palatable:

```
extern crate inflector;
use inflector::Inflector;

let capitalized = "some string".to_title_case();
```

Comment: The question of the user sounds more like he would want `.to_sentence_case()`.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help with naming things... This is awesome library and I never saw it before, but it's name is hard (for me) to remember and has functions that have hardly anything to do with actual inflection, one of them being your example.

Comment: If you're looking for a crate that does case conversions etc in <current year>, you probably want [`heck`](https://docs.rs/heck/latest/heck). However it does not have a `to_sentence_case()`, only a [`to_title_case()`](https://docs.rs/heck/latest/heck/trait.ToTitleCase.html#tymethod.to_title_case).

Comment: Also note that both `heck` and `inflector` discard punctuation and other characters that aren't valid in identifier names.

Answer (score 20):

It's not especially convoluted if you are able to limit your input to ASCII-only strings.

Since Rust 1.23, `str` has a `make_ascii_uppercase` method (in older Rust versions, it was available through the `AsciiExt` trait). This means you can uppercase ASCII-only string slices with relative ease:

```
fn make_ascii_titlecase(s: &mut str) {
    if let Some(r) = s.get_mut(0..1) {
        r.make_ascii_uppercase();
    }
}
```

This will turn `"taylor"` into `"Taylor"`, but it won't turn `"édouard"` into `"Édouard"`. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=84b5c2f973d83b7442c72da2d60858eb))

Use with caution.

Comment: Help a Rust newbie out, why is `r` mutable? I see that `s` is a mutable `str`. Ohhhh ok: I have the answer for my own question: `get_mut` (called here w/ a range) explicitly returns `Option<&mut>`.

Answer (score 8):

The OP's approach taken further:
*replace the first character with its uppercase representation*

```
let mut s = "foobar".to_string();
let r = s.remove(0).to_uppercase().to_string() + &s;
```

or

```
let r = format!("{}{s}", s.remove(0).to_uppercase());
println!("{r}");
```

works with Unicode characters as well eg. `"foobar"`

---

The first guaranteed to be an ASCII character, can changed to a capital letter in place:

```
let mut s = "foobar".to_string();
if !s.is_empty() {
    s[0..1].make_ascii_uppercase();  // Foobar
}
```

Panics with a non ASCII character in first position!

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way:

```
fn str_cap(s: &str) -> String {
  format!("{}{}", (&s[..1].to_string()).to_uppercase(), &s[1..])
}
```

If it is not an ASCII string:

```
fn str_cap(s: &str) -> String {
  format!("{}{}", s.chars().next().unwrap().to_uppercase(), 
  s.chars().skip(1).collect::<String>())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that is a bit slower than @Shepmaster's improved version, but also more *idiomatic*:

```rust
fn capitalize_first(s: &str) -> String {
    s.chars()
        .take(1)
        .flat_map(|f| f.to_uppercase())
        .chain(s.chars().skip(1))
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ICU4X](https://lib.rs/crates/icu) [now does title casing](https://blog.unicode.org/2023/10/icu4x-13-now-with-built-in-data-case.html) in a way that will handle a lot of internationalisation corner cases.  Copied from the [documentation](https://docs.rs/icu_casemap/latest/icu_casemap/titlecase/struct.TitlecaseMapper.html):

```
use icu_casemap::TitlecaseMapper;
use icu_locid::langid;

let cm = TitlecaseMapper::new();
let root = langid!("und");

let default_options = Default::default();

// note that the subsequent words are not titlecased, this function assumes
// that the entire string is a single segment and only titlecases at the beginning.
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("hEllO WorLd", &root, default_options), "Hello world");
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("Γειά σου Κόσμε", &root, default_options), "Γειά σου κόσμε");
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("नमस्ते दुनिया", &root, default_options), "नमस्ते दुनिया");
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("Привет мир", &root, default_options), "Привет мир");

// Some behavior is language-sensitive
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("istanbul", &root, default_options), "Istanbul");
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("istanbul", &langid!("tr"), default_options), "İstanbul"); // Turkish dotted i

assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("և Երևանի", &root, default_options), "Եւ երևանի");
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("և Երևանի", &langid!("hy"), default_options), "Եվ երևանի"); // Eastern Armenian ech-yiwn ligature

assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("ijkdijk", &root, default_options), "Ijkdijk");
assert_eq!(cm.titlecase_segment_to_string("ijkdijk", &langid!("nl"), default_options), "IJkdijk"); // Dutch IJ digraph
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem, notice I had to check if self is not ascii before transforming to uppercase.

```rust
trait TitleCase {
    fn title(&self) -> String;
}

impl TitleCase for &str {
    fn title(&self) -> String {
        if !self.is_ascii() || self.is_empty() {
            return String::from(*self);
        }
        let (head, tail) = self.split_at(1);
        head.to_uppercase() + tail
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", "bruno".title());
    println!("{}", "b".title());
    println!("{}", "".title());
    println!("{}", "ß".title());
    println!("{}", "".title());
    println!("{}", "བོད་སྐད་ལ".title());
}
```

Output

```
Bruno
B

ß

བོད་སྐད་ལ
```

Comment: Doesn't work if first character has two letters.

Comment: @Laire More precisely, it doesn't work for any Unicode character in the first position at all, since they are bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [get_mut examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.get_mut) I code something like this:

```
fn make_capital(in_str : &str) -> String {
    let mut v = String::from(in_str);
    v.get_mut(0..1).map(|s| { s.make_ascii_uppercase(); &*s });

    v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `cargo add ucfirst` in your project (or add `ucfirst = "0.1.0"` to your `Cargo.toml`). Then use the following in your project code:

```
use ucfirst::ucfirst;

let uppercased = ucfirst("apple banana"); // "Apple banana"
```

Full disclosure: this solution was shamelessly lifted from the
[leading response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406885) by [Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster).

Check out the ucfirst crate on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/ucfirst) and/or [github](https://github.com/qtfkwk/ucfirst).

Answer (score -1):

Since the method `to_uppercase()` returns a new string, you should be able to just add the remainder of the string like so.

this was tested in rust version 1.57+ but is likely to work in any version that supports slice.

```
fn uppercase_first_letter(s: &str) -> String {
        s[0..1].to_uppercase() + &s[1..]
    }
```

Comment: Same problem as the OP's problem: it does not work with Unicode characters in the first position.