# How do I convert reverse domain notation to PascalCase?

Tags: string, rust, converters

I want to convert `"foo.bar.baz"` to `"FooBarBaz"`. My input will always be only ASCII. I tried:

```
let result = "foo.bar.baz"
    .to_string()
    .split(".")
    .map(|x| x[0..1].to_string().to_uppercase() + &x[1..])
    .fold("".to_string(), |acc, x| acc + &x);
println!("{}", result);
```

but that feels inefficient.

Comment: You (and potential answerers) may like to read [Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406793/why-is-capitalizing-the-first-letter-of-a-string-so-convoluted-in-rust)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is a good start.  You could probably make it work without heap allocations in the "functional" style; I prefer putting complex logic into normal `for` loops though.

Also I don't like assuming input is in ASCII without actually checking - this should work with any string.

You probably could also use `String::with_capacity` in your code to avoid reallocations in standard cases.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=aa8e7a5e235296e97e7fd78981429ebf&version=stable)

```
fn dotted_to_pascal_case(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(s.len());
    for part in s.split('.') {
        let mut cs = part.chars();
        if let Some(c) = cs.next() {
            result.extend(c.to_uppercase());
        }
        result.push_str(cs.as_str());
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", dotted_to_pascal_case("foo.bar.baz"));
}
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't use this, but it amuses me that it works: `result.extend(cs.next().into_iter().flat_map(|c| c.to_uppercase()));`

Answer (score 3):

Stefan's answer is correct, but I decided to get rid of that first `String` allocation and go full-functional, without loops:

```
fn dotted_to_pascal_case(s: &str) -> String {
    s.split('.')
        .map(|piece| piece.chars())
        .flat_map(|mut chars| {
            chars
                .next()
                .expect("empty section between dots!")
                .to_uppercase()
                .chain(chars)
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", dotted_to_pascal_case("foo.bar.baz"));
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks similar. Do you know whether this will (pre)allocate the string with the correct length, or is it similar to the fold starting with an empty string?

Comment: @Stefan I took a look at the source of `collect` and it looks like it starts with an empty string and pushes individual characters ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/string.rs.html#1602-1606)). I doubt there is a significant difference between our approaches, my reasoning was primarily "not enough iterators" ;).

Comment: You could replace the `.expect` with `.iter()` if you want it to accept strings that contain consecutive dots.

Comment: `FromIterator<char>` for `String` can't usefully preallocate because any of those `char`s could be 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes long when encoded as UTF-8. `Chars::size_hint` ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#584-590)) has the inverse problem: it can't know how many `char`s the string contains because they can be variable length. (And let's not get into how changing a character's case can alter its length...)

Comment: @trentcl: It could definitely usefully pre-allocate, the result will *at least* have as many bytes as there are unicode characters, so it's never wasteful to start from that much. At worst, there'd be 2 growth if a lot of characters are actually 4 bytes wide, which is better than "lots".