# How can I implement a method to work with &str, Box<str>, Rc<str>, etc.?

Tags: rust

I have code that transforms a string reference in some way, e.g. takes the first letter

```
trait Tr {
    fn trim_indent(self) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> Tr for &'a str {
    fn trim_indent(self) -> Self {
        &self[..1] // some transformation here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "aaa".trim_indent();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Now I'm trying to generalize this code for any particular type that implements `AsRef<str>`. My final try was

```
use std::ops::Deref;

trait Tr<'a> {
    fn trim_indent(self) -> Deref<Target = str> + 'a + Sized;
}

impl<'a, T: AsRef<str>> Tr<'a> for T {
    fn trim_indent(self) -> Deref<Target = str> + 'a + Sized {
        self.as_ref()[..1] // some transformation here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "aaa".trim_indent();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

I'm stuck because without `Sized` I get an error that type is unknown at compile time, but with `Size` I get an error that I cannot use marker trait explicitly.

Comment: *e.g. takes the first letter* — that's not how Unicode works. See [Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38406793/155423) for a discussion of how this is the wrong view to have.

Comment: @Shepmaster okay, takes first byte and don't care what is it. Thank you for pointing that out, but it's just a badly written example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of what type you start with, the end type of slicing a `&str` is always a `&str` so your return type needs to be a `&str`.

Then it's a matter of implementing the trait for references to a type so that you can tie the input and output lifetimes together:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Tr<'a> {
    fn trim_indent(self) -> &'a str;
}

impl<'a, T> Tr<'a> for &'a T
where
    T: AsRef<str> + 'a,
{
    fn trim_indent(self) -> &'a str {
        &self.as_ref()[..1] // Take the first **byte**
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: &str = "aaa";
    println!("{}", s.trim_indent());

    let s: Box<str> = Box::from("bbb");
    println!("{}", s.trim_indent());

    let s: Rc<str> = Rc::from("ccc");
    println!("{}", s.trim_indent());
}
```

In this case, since all the types you've listed implement [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) anyway, you can just implement the trait for `&str` and all of the types can use it:

```
trait Tr {
    fn trim_indent(&self) -> &str;
}

impl Tr for str {
    fn trim_indent(&self) -> &str {
        &self[..1]
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why is capitalizing the first letter of a string so convoluted in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38406793/155423)