# Quick function to convert a String's first letter to uppercase?

Tags: string, rust, uppercase

Does anyone know a function that changes the first letter of a `String` to the uppercase equivalent?
Idealy, it would be used as so:

`let newfoo = first_letter_to_uppper_case("foobar".to_string())`, or
`let newfoo = "foobar".to_string().first_letter_to_uppper_case()`.

Comment: no, I'm asking for a How, not a Why. These are rather diferent questions, and the answer involving using a crate requires building its [26 dependancies](https://crates.io/crates/inflector/reverse_dependencies). adding that many dependancies is not a quick copy paste snippet of code.

Comment: The answer of Shep that yourself quote answer both how and why.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see it now. TBH i didn't consider it would be working code, given that he states it isn't code he'd use/write and it was what it *looked* like, and he'd rather use crates.io. Time to edit.

Comment: I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571882/3650362) to the other question that may suit your use case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a function used as so:
`let newfoo = first_letter_to_uppper_case("foobar".to_string())`
Try use the following:

```rust
fn main() {
  println!("{}", first_letter_to_uppper_case("foobar".to_string()));
}

fn first_letter_to_uppper_case (s1: String) -> String {
  let mut c = s1.chars();
  match c.next() {
    None => String::new(),
    Some(f) => f.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str(),
  }
}
```

If you want it as a function implimented on the string type, like `let newfoo = "foobar".to_string().first_letter_to_uppper_case()`, try:

```rust
pub trait FirstLetterToUppperCase {
  fn first_letter_to_uppper_case(self) -> String;
}

impl FirstLetterToUppperCase for String {
  fn first_letter_to_uppper_case(self) -> String {
    let mut c = self.chars();
    match c.next() {
      None => String::new(),
      Some(f) => f.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str(),
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  println!("{}", "foobar".to_string().first_letter_to_uppper_case());
}
```

However, these functions do not deal with non-ascii characters very well. For more information, see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406885/9761034)

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is plenty wrong you assume the "letter" is only one bytes, remember that String in Rust are UTF-8 String, convert the first character is not as trivial as you think.

Comment: See my latest edit, also, it is meant to be 'quick'. ;)

Comment: Well, In your implementation you create twice a string, that not what I would call quick also quick doesn't mean wrong and for finish I think that the answer you add is a the answer to this question.

Comment: by *quick*, I mean speed of writing quick. quick doesn't meen wrong *or* right.  My use for this is to capitalise the first word in a Lorem Ipsum sentance.  It's intended to replace Javascript's `sentence = sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sentence.slice(1);`. It's good enough for it's job.

Comment: It's now *correct*.

Comment: You don't have to call `.collect::<String>()` you can just call `.to_string()`